# Cannot resolve old react version

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have an old react template which I want to update. I get this error:

```
npm update                   
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: quiety-react@0.1.0
npm ERR! Found: react@18.2.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"^18.2.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^16.2.0 || ^17.0.0" from react-modal-video@1.2.10
npm ERR! node_modules/react-modal-video
npm ERR!   react-modal-video@"^1.2.9" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR!
npm ERR! For a full report see:
```

Do you know how I can fix this?

Comment: I think you either should use --force option or install react version 16.2.0 or 17 you can install it with "npm install react --save@version"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your project has "react" set in its `package.json` to a semver range which allows it to retrieve the latest React 18.

`react-modal-video` at version 1.2.10 only supports React 16 or 17, so version 18 is too high for that specific version of that package. Though it's worth noting this is probably because it's old and the author defined that restriction before React 18 was even available. Nonetheless, it's better to upgrade everything to be sure.

However, `react-modal-video`'s latest version supports React 18. So probably this can be fixed by executing `npm install --save react-modal-video@latest`.

Note the library may have had breaking changes since this is a major version bump (`1.x.x` to `2.x.x`), so you may need to brace for having to change the actual code to be compatible with this new version of `react-modal-video`.

To stop this kind of thing from happening in future, make sure to commit `package-lock.json` to version control. This will ensure the exact versions of everything installed are maintained across `npm install`'s.

Answer (score 0):

at the first time it's better to remove NPM and Node.js package in your system and then starting by

```
npm install -g npm
```

in CMD and installing Node.js from [nodejs-website](https://nodejs.org/en/download)
and after that you need to check your node.js and npm version by

```
npm -v
```

and
node -v
and if cmd indicates the version of node and npm you can start coding in react by
npx create_react_app your_project_name
or
npm -i -g create-react-app
so you can install react easily

I Hope can help you.